# Get the inserted variable for trigger

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I'm a bit new to using triggers, i'm trying to create a trigger that will update the stock when a product is ordered. I know this is wrong because I can't use ROW and I will also get an error when using the ROW prefix. So how should the trigger below be written?

```
CREATE TRIGGER changestock AFTER INSERT ON productorder
FOR EACH ROW
    UPDATE product
    SET product.stock = product.stock - ROW.orderamount
    WHERE product.productcode = ROW.productcode
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use NEW instead of ROW.. NEW refers to the record that was just inserted. You can get the columnNames from that record using NEW. before the column name:

```
CREATE TRIGGER changestock AFTER INSERT ON productorder
FOR EACH ROW
    UPDATE product
    SET product.stock = product.stock - NEW.orderamount
    WHERE product.productcode = NEW.productcode
```

Comment: It could be done here, but I'm not sure if this is the best place for that. I think he should handle that previously and only let the insert be done if there is stock